# Tracking a signal

Tags: matlab, estimation, classification, tracking

I have two signals representing steering wheel angles, one representing the driver’s inputs (red), while the other one represents the system’s reference signal (blue). 
[image]I want to estimate in real time the intention of the driver to catch the system’s angle and follow it.
The estimation is a value between 0 and 1 (1 : the driver is tracking the system’s reference; 0 : the driver is going in the opposite direction for example).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this a commercial problem?

Comment: No it's my masters project